# Can I Force MATLAB to quit after user presses Control-C?

Tags: bash, shell, matlab, signals

I'm running MATLAB (command line version) from a shell script, and I'd like it to preserve shell behavior where if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> it exits.  But instead it wants to keep control of the terminal and I (or my poor users after me) have to type `quit(1)` to make it quit and tell the shell it failed.

You can't intercept <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> with a `try`/`catch` block... any other ideas?  Anything I could do from the shell side to intercept the keystrokes before they get to MATLAB?

`onCleanup` seems like an option, but then I'd have to make the whole script thing into a function (it's already a dynamically generated `try`/`catch` block thing in a Makefile).  But if that's the only thing that will work, then I'll do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onCleanup`:

I wanted to do the same thing but after I read [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.matlab/browse_thread/thread/49e3e39ad0f5e7d9?pli=1) I used [onCleanup](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/oncleanup.html?) successfully. My problem was I had a server in Matlab that when pressing CTRL+C would keep `listen`ing on the port it was started on -> second run I would get a `bind` error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
stty quit ^C
```

but I have no matlab to test it.